# How can the cat get in and out from a second floor condo

Tags: cats

My cat is a 2 year old Siberian (elevated hunting drive). She has been an indoor/outdoor cat since I got her. She uses a small dog door to come and go as she pleases.

I am contemplating a move to a second story condo. I’m looking for suggestions as to how she may get in and out from the balcony or condo itself.

Comment: There's some great answers here already, and my suggestions don't answer your question directly, but I wanted to make a couple of additions if you might consider having a fully indoor cat: harness/leash train your cat, and create a "catio" on the balcony. Admittedly, it might be hard to transition a cat to full-time indoors. But with some patience and work, your cat can be happy and safe no matter where you move.

Answer (score 2):

You have different options here.

**install some stairs**

This you need to agree about with the other persons affected and the landlord. There are different option, as a ladder like thing to a window, a bridge from a tree nearby, or some steps at the rain-pipe. Some example pictures are [here](https://www.miaudo.de/media/image/8b/6b/2d/carlo259b3ba11cfcc9.jpg),[here](https://cattrip.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Katzenleiter_Cattrip_Beispiel1.jpg), [here](https://www.pinterest.de/pin/137782069842427260/) and [here](https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/s905e9fbc03ed2077/image/i41bf2cbc3893f0fc/version/1507814325/image.jpg). The aim would be, to let an open window for the cat all times.

**work with a schedule**

Also you can train a schedule with your cat. I assume you has noticed some pattern already how your cat spends a day. You can train times with it, when you will open the door for it. Or have some special call/noise to let it know "door is open now for 10 minutes" (like a spoon at a plate or similar, our neighbour did it with his 3 cats at feeding time and to close the door for the night)

**add a cat house**

This can give your cat a shelter until you come home or until you open the door. It is a insulated weather protected house near the door. You could even pretent it is a decorative flower stand for the unknown. And you can add a cat flap door with chip recognition, if you are worried other animals or cats would take it over. An example you can see [here](https://smallnature.de/diy-katzenhaus-eine-anleitung/) with lots of pictures how to make it and an instruction in german language.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a fire escape or outside staircase which is directly connected to a door/window in your unit, I would suggest installing a small dog door in that door or leaving the window open. However, if no such staircase exists I think the safest option would either be to let her outside when you are at home for a few hours and wait for her to return, or to simply transition her lifestyle into one that is completely indoors.