# Building outside ramp for cat

Tags: cats

We would like to build a wooden ramp to let our cat walk freely outside! Anybody aware of the min angle a cat will walk downwards without jumping.

Comment: Depends on the distance, texture, alternatives, landing conditions, and the cat's preferences and health.  Steps may be easier to navigate than a ramp.

Comment: Some ideas are shown in the links of this answer: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/how-can-the-cat-get-in-and-out-from-a-second-floor-condo/37384#37384